# Why putty takes time to deliver "ctrl +c" signals to process which are outputting heavily on stdout?

Tags: putty, gnu-screen

Whenever process is printing heavily on the `stdout`, if I try to `kill` process via sending signal `"ctrl + c"`, the process does not stop immediately. But if I am redirecting output in the file, process stops immediately if I press `"ctrl +c"`.
Infact If I am using gnu `screen`, and my process is outputting heavily on `stdout`, then I am not able to switch the `tab` as as well. Why is such behavior

Comment: I've always out this down to output buffering.

Answer (score 1):

The process can generate output much faster than the combination of network and screen can display it.

When you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> this key sequence may take some time to reach the server where the process is running due to network congestion caused by all the output; and when the process is killed, it can take significant time before all the output that has already been generated to be sent to the screen because of buffering in various places: firstly the network buffer on the server, packet buffers in transit on e.g. routers, input network queue on the display system, and then the input buffer of ssh / screen / X windows (depending on where you're running `screen`).

When using `screen` switching tabs has basically the same problem: the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> sequence may be delayed en route to the server, then `screen` may switch the displayed terminal immediately but this is only visible after everything that is already in the pipeline is displayed on your local system.